# Custom video thumbnails using YouTube API?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

How to upload custom thumbnails for an videos using php youtube-api .

I tried using Zend framework for youtube direct video upload which is working ,but i not able to find any custom thumbnails upload methods..

i tried the following code

```
 $parms = array('videoId => '' ,mediaUpload => '');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parms);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Content-Type: image/jpeg", 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['access_token']));
$return = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

error thrown
---------------
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: videoId",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "videoId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: videoId"
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the *required* `videoId`-parameter, and actually filling it in? The error states that it is missing.

Comment: just for example , i tried with videoId => 'pGM3wTq0z3Y'

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) for [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Zend was for GData, the older API.

You can use this example to upload custom thumbnail. Remember you should have the proper access for your channel to upload custom thumbnail.

```
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
 <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
<https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube object used to make all Data API requests.
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check if access token successfully acquired
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{

    // REPLACE with the channel that you want to upload into
    $videoId = "VIDEO_ID";

    // REPLACE with the path to your file that you want to upload for thumbnail
    $imagePath = "/path/to/file.png";

    // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
    // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Create a MediaFileUpload with resumable uploads
    $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('image/png', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($imagePath));

    // List associated content owners to get content owner id
    $setResponse = $youtube->thumbnails->set($videoId, array('mediaUpload' => $media));

    $uploadStatus = false;

    // Read file and upload chunk by chunk
    $handle = fopen($imagePath, "rb");
    while (!$uploadStatus && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($setResponse, $chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $thumbnailUrl = $uploadStatus['items'][0]['default']['url'];
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Thumbnail Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $videoId,
        $thumbnailUrl);
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<img src="%s">', $thumbnailUrl);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';


    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
      $state = mt_rand();
      $client->setState($state);
      $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Claim Uploaded</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?=$htmlBody?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This code helped me to fix my problem and it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Robi, can you post an example on how it got it to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Like the output states, you need to provide the "videoId" of the video you wish to upload a thumbnail for. It's a required parameter.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set#params

Comment: I tried with the above url ,but not clear and return as same error

Answer (score 0):

videoId is missing. Upload the video first and then create a thumbnail for the uploaded video with the videoId

Comment: that is I am asking ,I have upload the videos in youtube using Zend_Gdata_YouTube , but how to upload custom thumbnail via Zend_Gdata_YouTube (or) any other API ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  //CONVERT IMAGE FROM URL AND STORE
    $randomstr = generateRandomString();
    $thumbnail_url = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/BMFLzf-DXXU/hqdefault.jpg";   
    $ch = curl_init($thumbnail_url);
    $fp = fopen('videos/'.$randomstr.'.jpg', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: He wants to set a new thumbnail for the video

Comment: This code gives the thumbnail image in your harddrive from specifyed youtube url